# How remove React visible checkmark after form reset?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, checkbox

I'm working on a React app with a button to reset a form. When the user clicks the "Reset" button, all the states revert to their original values. But a checkmark remains selected even after all the other data clears. It does appear to reset the state, but the checkmark is still visible and confusing to the user. I understand that defaultChecked is read on the initial load, but the checkmark remains even if I remove defaultChecked completely, so I'm not sure where the problem is. I suspect the solution might involve onChange, but I haven't been able to get that to work. Any help appreciated.

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

const clearSearch = () => {
 setResults([]);
 setQuery("");
 setFormat("");
 setChecked(false); 
}

<label>
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    id="searchAll"
    defaultChecked={checked}
    onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
    />
    Search all formats
 </label>


<button className="btn btn-danger" 
  onClick={event => {
  event.preventDefault();
   clearSearch();
    }}>
    Reset
 </button>
```

App.js on GitHub https://github.com/irene-rojas/loc/blob/master/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checkbox is actually an [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) input, which probably isn't what you want (it usually isn't in React). That is because, although you've got the `onChange` event wired up to a handler which sets state, you're not reading back from that state into the input. Except in the `defaultChecked` attribute - which doesn't control whether it's *actually* checked or not.

You need to use the `checked` attribute, which for a checkbox is essentially equivalent to the `value` attribute of a text or numeric input:

```
<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  id="searchAll"
  checked={checked}
  onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
/>
```

(I've removed your `defaultChecked` attribute, as I don't think you want it - but feel free to put it back in if you do. The important thing is having a `checked` attribute that reads from the `checked` state value.)

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much! And for clarifying that defaultChecked is uncontrolled.

Comment: You're welcome. And apologies, I probably didn't phrase my answer well enough - being uncontrolled is nothing to do with `defaultChecked`, it's just a consequence of the fact that you were not setting the `checked` attribute depending on the component state, which meant that the "actual state" (whether the user sees a checked or unchecked checkbox) was being controlled by the DOM, rather than by React.